# Convert Text or Varchar to Decimal type

Tags: sql, t-sql, decimal, varchar

In the column `[Return rate]`, I have values like :

```
20.0%
17.1% 
etc
```

In my query, I want to use this values in a calculation.

So first, I replace the `'%'` by an empty string `''` :

```
REPLACE([Return Rate], '%' ,'') AS [Test]
```

This works, and I get values like '20.0' when [Return rate] was '20.0%'.

Then I try to use this [Test] value in a calculation, for instance:

```
(REPLACE([Return Rate], '%' ,'') * 10) AS [Test]
```

But I logically obtain an error, so I try to convert this text value to perform my calculation:

```
CAST ( REPLACE([Current Xelus FE Return Rate], '%' ,'') AS decimal(2,1))  [Decimal Test]
```

And it's here that I get the error:

> ```
> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

Has someone the answer to this error? 
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your rows contain null values, you will get this error.  Try an IsNull, like this:

```
CAST( 
 IsNull( 
  REPLACE([Current Xelus FE Return Rate], '%' ,'') 
 , '0.0')
AS decimal(5,1))  [Decimal Test]
```

If your data contains non-numeric values (as you mentioned, values like 'N/A'), you can elimimate them with the IsNumeric() function:

```
CAST( 
  CASE WHEN IsNumeric(
    IsNull( 
      REPLACE([Current Xelus FE Return Rate], '%' ,'') 
    , '0.0')
  ) = 1 THEN IsNull(REPLACE([Current Xelus FE Return Rate], '%' ,''),'0.0')
  ELSE '0.0' 
  END
AS decimal(5,1))  [Decimal Test]
```

Comment: Thanks all, but it's seems that NULL values and others (like 'N/A') are the cause of this issue.

Do someone know how if there is a SQL or T-SQL function that verify if the value in parameters is a numeric value? (for instance I will be able to make a special case for values like 'N/A' etc).

Answer (score -1):

Try casting it to FLOAT - decimal(2,1) is not enough:

```
CAST ( REPLACE([Current Xelus FE Return Rate], '%' ,'') AS FLOAT)
```

Then you should be able to do further calculations

```
CAST ( REPLACE([Current Xelus FE Return Rate], '%' ,'') AS FLOAT) * 10
```

Comment: Float should not be used if you are planning to use calculations, You will get rounding errors.